# How to pipe to a file (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file

I have created some image data which I've obtained from pixels. Anyway, now I would like to write a file using [save-pixels](https://github.com/scijs/save-pixels), but the docs only give

```
var savePixels = require("save-pixels")
...
savePixels(pixels, "png").pipe(process.stdout)
```

How to rewrite this such that it writes it to a file with a specific name ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the file system module included with node. Something like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var savePixels = require("save-pixels");
var myFile = fs.createWriteStream("myOutput.txt");
...
savePixels(pixels, "png").pipe(myFile);
```

Comment: Thnx, that did the trick! As soon as I can I'll mark this as the correct answer!

Comment: You beat me to it sir, I was going to answer exactly that. The only thing I'd add is in case you do this inside a gulp-task or inside a function, it can be important to `return` the stream so it can be piped again. +1